# Sapper/Svelte: How do I add markdown files?

Tags: markdown, svelte, sapper

I am creating a blog using Sapper using the default [sapper-template-rollup](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template-rollup).

In the blog folder, it does mention about generating data from markdown files. But I can't find how to do it?

Comment: Look for a markdown loader plugin for your module bundler (webpack, rollup ..)

Comment: It's pretty straightforward, you can make use of the `marked` package and you can absolutely refer to how svelte has built its own blog page. Check it out here https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/site/src/routes/blog/_posts.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 2020-06-14:

There is a [GitHub version](https://github.com/rdela/kokodokai) as well now (since 2019-11-11) that publishes with Netlify and has a [custom domain](https://kokodokai.com/) added. So unlike the GitLab version, it does not use Sapper's [base URL to alter the base path](https://gitlab.com/rdela/sapper-v3#gitlab-pages-adjustments) that is necessary with GitLab and GitHub pages unless you add a custom domain.

Original answer 2019-10-24:

You may find [this repo](https://gitlab.com/rdela/sapper-v3) helpful. I also have an [open PR](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template/pull/109) on the Sapper Template repo, first revising the old Markdown branch in Jan. 2019 and then adding Svelte 3 support in May 2019, but it is probably easier to look at and clone [my repo on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/rdela/sapper-v3), plus it has more current dependency updates I have not added to the PR yet.

Comment: See also this [Sapper blog template](https://github.com/Charca/sapper-blog-template) via Brittney in the Sapper channel on the [Svelte Discord](https://svelte.dev/chat), a great place to ask questions and chat.

Comment: I see that all the posts will have a link right after the Top-Level Domain Ex `www.example.com/post1`, `www.example.com/post2`. But what if someone using the template wants to categorize the posts. Ex `www.example.com/svelte-posts/post1`, `www.example.com/vuejs-posts/post1`

Comment: @JustineKizhak So you are looking to add categories on one blog or have 2 separate blogs?

Comment: Is there a difference between categories and 2 separate blogs on the same website? I was thinking of categories of blogs like tech blog and another blog of travelling etc. Right now I don't care if there are no categories but in future, I might. So right now I want to put in the work of dealing with the codebase, later then I just have to focus on the content.

Comment: @JustineKizhak If you want traditional WordPress-style categories I would add that to the markdown front matter of the posts ([Jekyll docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/#predefined-variables-for-posts)) and then create a category page template using [dynamic parameters](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Routing), with links to any categories in your individual post templates as well.

Comment: @JustineKizhak However, if there are a limited number of categories you know ahead of time, and you want the category in the URL before the post name, it might be simpler, though limiting over time, to have separate blogs/folders of posts and use those the way the [Svelte site uses the `blog` folder](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/tree/master/site/src/routes). This would not work well if you wanted a traditional chronological index of all of the posts from any category though, so if you did want that use the front matter approach above and not worry about the URL for individual posts.

Comment: @JustineKizhak Also in my experience, tags are almost always better than categories, because you can add as many as you like. What if you wrote a post comparing Svelte and Vue? Why not have it appear in both? Then you want [tags not categories](https://start.duckduckgo.com/?q=tags+vs+categories). WordPress has a long, confusing history with this where I think they finally made categories behave like tags because they got sick of dealing with people using categories when they wanted tags and complaining.

Comment: @JustineKizhak added a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674044/how-do-i-add-categories-or-tags-to-a-svelte-sapper-markdown-site) about this to help future searchers, please feel free to continue the conversation or add your own answers over there.

Comment: Now I see, tags does offer more flexibility but about categories can't we do something in `js` to parse and save blogs of different categories in separate json files like `svelte-posts.json`, `vue-posts.json` as I understand a post can't belong to more than 1 category. So a `[category]/index.svelte` could only fetch the respective `json` and render it chronologically. I can see myself using both categories and tags. Categories as groups and tags for filtering. But I guess for filtering, I will have to do server-side setup too.

Comment: I will try to figure out a solution and post on your question. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2):

I published https://github.com/mikenikles/sapper-template-with-markdown which shows how to use the default Sapper template, but uses `*.md` files for the blog post content.

The main change was in `src/routes/blog/_posts.js` where I replaced the content with:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const frontMatter = require('front-matter');
const marked = require('marked');

const posts = fs.readdirSync('./src/posts').map(postFilename => {
  const postContent = fs.readFileSync(`./src/posts/${postFilename}`, {
    encoding: 'utf8'
  });
  const postFrontMatter = frontMatter(postContent);
  return {
    title: postFrontMatter.attributes.title,
    slug: postFrontMatter.attributes.slug,
    html: marked(postFrontMatter.body)
  }
});

posts.forEach(post => {
    post.html = post.html.replace(/^\t{3}/gm, '');
});

export default posts;
```

Then, each blog post is stored in `src/posts` as a Markdown file with the following format:

```
---
title: 'What is Sapper?'
slug: 'what-is-sapper'
---

Your markdown content.
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have more lick using [MDsveX](https://github.com/pngwn/MDsveX) which is a Svelte Markdown processor, created by one of the core community members.

However yes, you can also just use `marked` or `snarkdown` (which is what I use), the same way as you would use any other library - simply import it and pass your markdown code to it.

Answer (score 1):

I went with @Antony Jones's approach. I put the `.md` files in my routes/ folder and used [Svelte Preprocess Markdown](https://alexxnb.github.io/svelte-preprocess-markdown/), setting it up in my rollup config to process `.md` files (turning them into `.svelte` files). The `.md` files are organized into sub-folders within the routes/ folder, and each folder has an index page that will list links to the pages made by the files or folders inside. Here is a link to the repo if you want to check it out: [link](https://github.com/RossHathaway/jack-christensen). It is still a work in progress.

As @rdela said in his comments, though, this approach is less flexible than processing the posts using your own code to get the front matter as they do in the template repo, and then filtering the posts, putting them into folders based on tags in their front matter, or something like that.